# How to number each equation of simultaneous equations grouped by a left curly brace?

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering, amsmath

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
ax + by =c \\
px + qy = r
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

produces an output as follows.

[image]

What I want to achieve is as follows.

[image]

Is there any idea?

My attempt is as follows, but it does not compile.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
ax + by =c \tag{OK}\\
px + qy = r \tag{Yes}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll have to refer to the [MathMode document](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) , and at page 104 there is exactly what are you looking for. Basically it is the addition of `\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)` after every line inside a fake `cases` environment.

Comment: Please don't use left brace that points to nothing for grouping. It's redundant. Use matrix form if you want to combine `\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\p&q\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c\\r\end{pmatrix}` etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See the `empheq` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{empheq} % autoloads mathtols and amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
ax + by =c \\
px + qy = r 
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @daleif, I tried your code, but some equations are not aligned: \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\frac{dQ(t)}{dt} = R_a(t) - R_d(t)\\ 
\frac{dQ(t)}{dt} = 0\\ 
\frac{dq(t)}{dt} = ir(t) - r_d(t) \\ 
q(0)=0
\end{empheq}

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi then add some `&`'s where you wanted alignments. The Op did not include alignments in the question

Answer (score 7):

There is the main MWE of a simple example involving multimple cases:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
 ax + by =c & \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\\
 ax + by =c & \refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
\end{array}
\right.
\]
%
\end{document}
```

If you want to change the spacing of the delimiter before the equations, add this lines to the preamble of the MWE:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{array}{%
 \addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-3.5pt}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
}
```

Comment: That will not place the quation numbers at the right edge of the text block. The resorting to this sort of thing, one should really go and ask for help ;-)

Comment: Yes, maybe it will do something adding `\hfill` to the single argument but I think that your answer is way more elegant and simple than mine :-)

Comment: It will not, at least then the math will not be in the center.

Comment: You're right, complied and verified, but still it's my first answer so I'll learn with time `:-)`.